# flutter how to make an modal route animation come from the bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, overlay

I need to make the modal route animation come from the bottom when clicked, however the only animation that I managed to do is the fade away and the spin animation.

It is an overlay that is called when the user clicks a button to explain it.

Here is the build page

```
@override        
Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
    return Material(
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      // make sure that the overlay content is not cut off
      child: SafeArea(
        child: _buildOverlayContent(context),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and here is the build transitions:

```
      @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    // You can add your own animations for the overlay content
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: animation,
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: animation,
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried to use slide transitions from several ways but it doesnt seem to work any time I try. It either leads to an error or simply doesnt work.

(One of my tries)

```
  Animation<Offset> animated() {


   Animation<Offset> anime;
    return anime;
  }

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    //You can add your own animations for the overlay content
    return SlideTransition(
      position: animated(),
      child: child,
    );
  }
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `page_transition` package:

https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition

You can use the `bottomToTop` transition to achieve this.

```
Navigator.push(
  context, 
  PageTransition(
    type: PageTransitionType.bottomToTop, 
    child: DetailScreen()
  )
);
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to work with the overlay "class HomepageOverlay extends ModalRoute<void>"

Comment: Any ideas in how to make it work with a modal route?

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you're looking for:

```
  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {

    return SlideTransition(
      position: Tween(
        begin: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
        end: Offset.zero,
      ).animate(animation),
      child: child,
    );
  }
```